# Swift - UITextField get the text programmatically from for loop for later use

Tags: loops, for-loop, text, swift, uitextfield

Hi I have a UITextFields in for loop in function example:

```
func textfieldsinfunc(){
 for....{
   //5 times for example
   var textField:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(addedNX, fieldHeight, 143, 30))
   textField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
   self.scrollView.addSubview(textField)
 }
}
```

How to get the text of these 5 textFields outside the function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tag to identify UIView.

```
for index in 1...5 {
    //5 times for example
    var textField:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(10, 100, 143, 30))
    textField.borderStyle = .RoundedRect
    textField.tag = index
    self.scrollView.addSubview(textField)
}
```

and use viewWithTag outside the function

```
let textField: UITextField = scrollView.viewWithTag(1) as UITextField
```